# Ctrl opening new tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chromebook

I have a problem with my Chromebook. Every time I hit the Ctrl key it opens a new tab. I am trying to copy and paste for a paper and no matter what I hit with the Ctrl key (or just by itself) it opens a new tab.

I updated my computer, I removed my t key and checked to make sure it's not stuck.

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you have a USB keyboard that you can plug in, to test if it does the same thing? You could also try to re-install Chrome (I'm assuming you're using Google Chrome). You can also try to hold down CTRL + SHIFT keys at the same time for about 3-5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when you're logged in to the Chromebook Guest account?  If yes do a Hardware Reset:

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3227606

If not disable any Chrome extensions you may have installed recently.  If that doesn't fix it, do a Chrome settings reset.

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3296214?hl=en